# Interpolate String within an annotation class

Tags: dart

I am trying to find a way to interpolate a string with in an annotation, since the parameters of an annotation class constructor have to be constant i had to skip the `$`, then replace `'\$'` with `'$'` whenever i need to interpolate, the following example clarifies what i am trying to do

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

    void main() {
          var c = new Chicken('aaaa','blue',99);
          var templateValue = (reflectClass(Chicken).metadata.where((a)=>a.reflectee.runtimeType == Template).first.reflectee as Template).value;
          print(interpolater.interpolate(c,templateValue));
        }

        class Template{
          final String value;
          const Template(this.value);
        }

        @Template('<div>name:\${context.name} color:\${context.color} age:\${context.age}</div>')
        class Chicken{
          String name;
          String color;
          int age;
          Chicken(this.name,this.color,this.age);
        }

        class interpolater{
          static String interpolate(Object context,String s){
            s = s.replaceAll('\\\$', '\$'); 
            return s;
          }
        }
```

but it does not seem to work, anyway to make something like that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the string in a function like `templateStr` below:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Context {
  String name = "some name";
  String color = "some color";
  int age = 15;
}

void main() {
  var c = new Chicken('aaaa','blue',99);
  var templateValue = (reflectClass(Chicken).metadata.where((a)=>a.reflectee.runtimeType == Template).first.reflectee as Template).value(c);
  print(templateValue);
}

class Template{
  final Function value;
  const Template(this.value);
  String getValue(context) => value(context);
}

String templateStr(context) => '<div>name:${context.name} color:${context.color} age:${context.age}</div>';

@Template(templateStr)
class Chicken{
  String name;
  String color;
  int age;
  Chicken(this.name,this.color,this.age);
}
```

Comment: great but what about when the time comes to  interpolate?

Comment: yes thats my interpolate but nothing happens it prints the string as it is

Comment: Just add another comment if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: still the Interpolate does not happen, the only change i did to my above code is i added r in the annotation and removed the replace statement and i am looking to make something like the highest voted answer in  that question to work

Comment: I updated my answer with your code modified to a working example.

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation is a grammatical part of Dart, it is recognized while parsing.

If you take a string and replace "\$" in the string with "$", you will just get a string with "$" in it. It wasn't an interpolation at compile time, so it's not an interpolation now.

You can think of string interpolation like "$a foo $b" as a shorthand for `"" + a.toString() + " foo " + b.toString() + ""`. The string interpolation is a *string expression*, but it's not a string itself - every time it is evaluated, it evaluates to a *new* string. (Well, a compile-time constant string interpolation is a string value at runtime, because it is only evaluated once, at compile time).

If you want to make a template which is filled in at runtime, then you also have to make the code that does the filling in.

One alternative is to not use a string, but instead a use a function in the annotation:

```dart
// Top-level function is compile-time constant.
myTemplate(context) => 
  '<div>name:${context.name} color:${context.color} age:${context.age}</div>';

@Template(myTemplate)
class Chicken {...}
```

And then you can extract the function from the annotation the same way you currently do, and then call it with the chicken. This uses a real string interpolation to build the string, and it delays the evaluation until you have the context available.

(If you have access to annotating the class, why don't you just add a method to the class instead. Then you won't need mirrors. Or if you don't want to add a method to the object, maybe make it static, and then look it up using mirrors)